# Qt program crashes when using insertText

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

I'm trying to display some information in my Qt program with the `QPlainTextEdit`, which I included with the Qt Designer. But when i try to display something with

```
pTextEdit->insertPlainText("text");
```

my program crashes on execution. When I try to declare the object myself

```
QTextEdit *txt = new QTextEdit();
```

it doesn't work either.

The only time it works is when I create the object in the main.cpp. But I need to display the information in my widget not in another window.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

working:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    QTextEdit *txt = new QTextEdit();
    txt->setText("Hello, world!");
    txt->append("Appending some text…");

    txt->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

not working (object created by Qt Designer):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow( QWidget *parent ) :

... initialization list ...

{
    ui->setupUi( this );

    console->setPlainText("text");

    .. other stuff ...
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to handle this logic in your main window code file? Is so, have you included <QTextEdit>?

Comment: I think you should put your key part of the code in the question, what does your main.cpp look like, and what does your widget class look like?

Comment: I don't do anything in the main.cpp, there is just what was generated when the project was created.

`
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "include/dynamixel_sdk.h"
#include <QApplication>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}`

I only wrote something in it to find the source of the crash. The <QTextEdit> is included.

Comment: Three questions: 1)did you try debugging (set a breakpoint before the `setPlainText(...)` line)?, 2)if yes, then what happened during step by step debugging? and 3)did you actually create an instance of the `QTextEdit`? All I see in your constructor is a call `console->...` but no where before that an`console = new QTextEdit(...)` line. Since you are not calling `ui->console->...` I assume that it's not part of the designer form hence you need to allocate the memory yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take into consideration that [`insertPlainText`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#insertPlainText) inserts text at current cursor position, so I think you may have problems if cursor is not set (no focus, for example). You may try:

```
txt->setPlainText("your text");
```

Or, if want to append:

```
txt->setPlainText(txt->toPlainText() + "appended text");
```

Comment: Of course, you can try setting the cursor using `setTextCursor`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but I also tried `txt->setPlainText("text");` it had the same effect.

Comment: May you please publish more complete examples for both the failing and the working cases?

Comment: I added the sample in the question ^^

Comment: I think you should be using `ui->console->setPlainText` (or whatever the name of the QTextEdit is). The QTextEdit is constructed *after* the `setupUi`, so if you copied it before you are using a uninitialized pointer.

Comment: That was it. I´m feeling so stupid right now. Thanks a lot !